# how to have a tab be open by default with angular and bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I have two tabs, that I can open by clicking either, but I'd like the first one to be opened by default..

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-class="{active: activeTab == 'implementation'}">
        <a ng-click="activeTab='implementation'">Implementation</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active: activeTab == 'videos'}">
        <a ng-click="activeTab='videos'">Videos</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div ng-show="activeTab=='implementation'"  >
    <h4>test heading</h4>
</div>

<div ng-show="activeTab=='videos'">
    <h4>test heading</h4>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about just initializing activeTab?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" ng-init="activeTab = 'implementation'">
    <li ng-class="{active: activeTab == 'implementation'}">
        <a ng-click="activeTab='implementation'">Implementation</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active: activeTab == 'videos'}">
        <a ng-click="activeTab='videos'">Videos</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```